# Any free service like Google Apps?

Tags: email, google-workspace

Google Apps offers a good opportunity to host emails externally. Definitely, Google should not be alone in this market, but I've not heard of any other alternative. Is there any other company offering free email hosting?

Comment: You also have [Outlook.com](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-outlook-on-custom-domain/24699/) now!

Comment: why not contructive? this is a good question

Answer (score 6):

Zoho.com offers 3 Free email accounts, as well as a free account on their CRM application. I'm sure they have free offers for other products of theirs.